# Would App store accept a program that bundles a Python interpreter?

Tags: mac-appstore

I have developed [a Python IDE for beginners](http://thonny.org), which bundles Python 3.6 and a recent (ie. not-too-buggy) Tcl/Tk (neither is available in macOS by default)

At the moment the users install it from a dmg file, but as recent macOS versions have become more suspicious (hostile?) towards non-app-store apps, the users (often with very low technical abilities) have more and more trouble with the installation.

Is there a chance that such application will be accepted to the App Store? Do you know any examples of similar apps, that are in the App Store?

Comment: Pythonista sounds similar but not for beginners like your app. More for Python users. It's available on App Store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Before the Mac App Store

To improve your user's experience, you may be able to avoid *needing* to be in the Mac App Store.

- [Code sign](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide) your existing application and macOS's hostility towards your app will vanish.
- Improve your application's first run experience using [LetsMove](https://github.com/potionfactory/LetsMove). This open source framework will automatically copy the application into the `/Applications` folder and eject the disk image.
- Use the open source [Sparkle](https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle) framework to add automated software updating to your application.

Just code signing your application will dramatically improve the first run experience for your users.

## App Store Requirements

If your application meets the requirements below, then it will likely be accepted into the Mac App Store:

- conforms to the [App Store Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/);
- supports being sandboxed;
- can be bundled within a self contained application.

### Ask Apple's iTunes Connect Team

You can [contact Apple's iTunes Connect](http://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/contactus) and talk to them before committing to significant development work. They are best placed to know what is likely to be accepted or not.